# Eclipse IDE changing class status to 'deleted' does not stick

Tags: class, xml

I am trying to delete a class in production.I have deleted 2 classes successfully by changing the status of the corresponding metadata.xml to **deleted**.But in one class while I am trying to change the status to **deleted** and save it.It is automatically getting changed to active.I don't have ant set up.What is the possible reason for this.Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is because there may be dependent components and this will not allow you to delete .The solution is to find the dependency and delete first dependent components and then delete the parent component .